# Can we show flat 50% profit under section 44ADA in ITR?

Tags: income-tax, india

Can a professional with side business income claim 50% profit as part of section 44ADA while filing ITRs?

What if the real profit is more than 50%, let's say, 80%?
Is such a professional safe to claim 50% profit and enjoy the benefit as part of 44ADA?

Total turnover receipts are less than 50 lakhs per annum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An salaried individual can declare additional income from specified professions under 44ADA at 50% of gross receipts irrespective of actual. This would be treated as final income.

Comment: So this is not questionable at all? Even when actual profit is more than 50%?

Comment: @maverick yes. That's what presumptive means. It doesn't matter what it is actually.